# Remove dots inside a tags in php

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace

How to remove dots inside a tags in php by preg_replace ?

i tried with this code:

```
$str = 'out . out<a href="http://example.com">inside. in.si. d .e</a> outside';

$str = preg_replace("/(<a.*>.*)[.](.*<\/a>)/","$1$2", $str);
```

correct output is:

```
out . out<a href="http://example.com">inside insi d e</a> outside
```

But this only clears one dot.

thanks

Comment: What is your expected result above?

Comment: `$result = str_replace('.', '', $str);`

Comment: thanks for response. 
My expected result is to remove all dots within the a tag.

Comment: Its a good idea to show the required output as well, so there is no confusion in our minds

Comment: And do it as part of your question. You can use the `edit` link to amend your question

Comment: $result = str_replace('.', '', $str); This code clears all dots. But only the dots inside a tag must be deleted.

Comment: See also "You should not parse html with regular expressions": https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4883924